# Delphi 7 Windows 7 Can't set active direcory, when a dpr file is opened from windows explorer

Tags: delphi

I used to open Delphi 7 dpr files from windows explorer. Delphi used to update current save directory.

But from windows 7 and on this doesnt work. I open dpr from windows explorer, add a new form. When I try to save new unit, delphi tries to save file to last known directory.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you it set to run as administrator? You could try windows compatibility settings to see if that works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Delphi 7 uses the older [Common Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645524.aspx) API for opening/saving files ([`GetOpenFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927.aspx) and [`GetSaveFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646928.aspx) functions). That API was replaced with the newer [Common Item Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913.aspx) API ([`IFileOpenDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775834.aspx) and [`IFileSaveDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775688.aspx) interfaces) in Vista.

The behavior you describe is simply how the old API works in modern Windows versions.

Per the [`OPENFILENAME` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx) documentation:

> `lpstrInitialDir`
>   Type: LPCTSTR
>
> The initial directory. The algorithm for selecting the initial directory varies on different platforms.
>
> Windows 7:
>
> 1. **If `lpstrInitialDir` has the same value as was passed the first time the application used an Open or Save As dialog box, the path most recently selected by the user is used as the initial directory.**
> 2. Otherwise, if `lpstrFile` contains a path, that path is the initial directory.
> 3. Otherwise, if `lpstrInitialDir` is not NULL, it specifies the initial directory.
> 4. If `lpstrInitialDir` is NULL and the current directory contains any files of the specified filter types, the initial directory is the current directory.
> 5. Otherwise, the initial directory is the personal files directory of the current user.
> 6. Otherwise, the initial directory is the Desktop folder.
>
> Windows 2000/XP/Vista:
>
> 1. **If `lpstrFile` contains a path, that path is the initial directory.**
> 2. Otherwise, `lpstrInitialDir` specifies the initial directory.
> 3. Otherwise, if the application has used an Open or Save As dialog box in the past, the path most recently used is selected as the initial directory. However, if an application is not run for a long time, its saved selected path is discarded.
> 4. If `lpstrInitialDir` is NULL and the current directory contains any files of the specified filter types, the initial directory is the current directory.
> 5. Otherwise, the initial directory is the personal files directory of the current user.
> 6. Otherwise, the initial directory is the Desktop folder.